# IJCADで、ダイアログ内のデバッグ(ブレークしてトレース)はできないのでしょうか。

Tags: .net, ijcad, vb.net

IJCAD2023で、VB.NETで開発をしています。
ダイアログ内のデバッグを行いたいのですが、ダイアログ内でブレークを設定すると「アプリケーションはブレークモードになっています」と表示されて、ソースが表示されません。
ダイアログ内でブレークはできないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> ダイアログ内でブレークはできないのでしょうか。

できないと考えられます。
IJCADのヘルプセンターで公開している資料を見ると制限事項のようです。
https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/15147656759833